# Sql query for Actuals met forecast for a given week

Tags: sql

Table: UnitsSold
Columns:

- ProductID
- Quantity
- Date
- ForecastOrActual – can be “A” for actual and “F” for forecast.

Sample Data would look like this:

```
UnitsSold
ProductID       Quantity    Date            ForecastOrActual
Widget          100         1-June-2015     F
Widget          120         1-June-2015     A
Gizmo           90          1-June-2015     F
Gizmo           80          1-June-2015     A
Doohickey       200         1-June-2015     A
```

I am looking for a sql query that returns a single aggregate metric indicating how well actuals met forecast for a given week.  Also any  assumptions

Appreciate your support. Thanks

Comment: What would the expected result look like?

Comment: please edit your quesion which kind of output you needed?

Comment: Post your expected result

Comment: Determining if forecasts match what actually happened.

Comment: Just post your expected output.Then only readers clearly understand.

Comment: select product,sum(qty) as Metric,format(date,'yyyyMM') as Period from
(
SELECT product,quantity*-1 as qty,date FROM [dbo].[Sample] where ForecastOrActual='A'
union
SELECT product,quantity as qty,date FROM [dbo].[Sample] where ForecastOrActual='F'
) A
group by A.product,A.Date  ## I want same logic to be applied for week

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Irrespective of version i would like to know how i can achieve with the help of query. Any version will do like Ansi 92

Comment: Don't post code or additional information in comments [edit] your question

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to write the code since the info you have here but idea is this:

```
WITH 
  cte_A AS
( SELECT qty,product, DATEPART( wk, DATE) AS WEEK 
  WHERE FORCAST='A'
  GROUP BY product,DATEPART( wk, DATE))
, cte_F AS
( SELECT qty,product, DATEPART( wk, DATE) AS WEEK 
  WHERE FORCAST='F'
  GROUP BY product,DATEPART( wk, DATE))
SELECT cte_A.product,cte_A.week,
CASE 
WHEN cte_F.qty - cte_A.qty >0 THEN 'Not met forcast'
WHEN cte_F.qty - cte_A.qty <0 THEN 'Met forcast'
END AS result
FROM cte_A join cte_F 
ON cte_A.product=cte_F.product
AND cte_A.week=cte_F.week
```

If you give me more information, I might be able to make this code better for you.

The DATEPART function will give you the number of week in the year for any day, you can then use that number for each year if your data spans over multiple years.
Hope this helps.

Update based on your comments:

For a better logic (-100 to 100) performance you can change this to:

```
WITH 
  cte_A AS
( SELECT qty,product, DATEPART( wk, DATE) AS WEEK 
  WHERE FORCAST='A'
  GROUP BY product,DATEPART( wk, DATE))
, cte_F AS
( SELECT qty,product, DATEPART( wk, DATE) AS WEEK 
  WHERE FORCAST='F'
  GROUP BY product,DATEPART( wk, DATE))
SELECT cte_A.product,cte_A.week,
CASE WHEN cte_F.qty = cte_A.qty THEN 0
ELSE 100.0*(cte_A.qty - cte_F.qty) / cte_F.qty As Performance
FROM cte_A join cte_F 
ON cte_A.product=cte_F.product
AND cte_A.week=cte_F.week
```

Comment: The requirement was given for assessment mentioning like this..The role require you to be able to analyze large quantities of data and present metrics indicating if company is improving or getting worse in certain areas.  A good example of this is determining if our forecasts match what actually happened.
Write an SQL query which returns a single aggregate metric indicating how well actuals met forecast for a given week.  What assumptions did you make?

Comment: This will give you the aggregate, based on your logic. I think you are also asking what the logic should be, which based on your data, your logic is sound. What I can add to it is a more "gauge" type of measure like 0 to 100 . instead of 0 or 1 (met forcast or not)

Comment: I added a new performance logic just to give u the idea, let me know if you needed more help

Comment: I am posting the requirement for the sake of clarity.. Appreciate if you can refine
Table: UnitsSold
Columns:
• ProductID
• Quantity
• Date
• ForecastOrActual – can be “A” for actual and “F” for forecast.

Sample Data would look like this:
UnitsSold
ProductID  Quantity Date ForecastOrActual
Widget 100 1-June-2015 F
Widget 120 1-June-2015 A
Gizmo 90 1-June-2015 F
Gizmo 80 1-June-2015 A
Doohickey 200 1-June-2015 A

Write an SQL query which returns a single aggregate metric indicating how well actuals met forecast for a given week.  What assumptions did you make?

Comment: @Eswar: don't post additional information as comments. Edit your question and add that as  [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: oh so you want one number for each week. I thought it was each week and product.